# Как обновить стручки parse?

Tags: swift, parse.com, cocoapods

Обновились компоненты и пришли ошибки в стручке Parse. Как сделать обновление версии? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробывал в ручную исправить, но в конце в каком то методе выдает красную ошибку.

Comment: VAndrJ истину глаголит, на предупреждения не обращай внимания. У меня в проекте аналогично (если это успокоит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не ошибки, а предупреждения. Вы можете просто игнорировать их и ждать что в новых версиях возможно исправят.

А можете скрыть эти предупреждения, чтобы не раздражали. В `podfile` допишите к нужному поду

```
:inhibit_warnings => true
```

в частности, для parse:

```
pod 'Parse', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

и сделайте

```
pod install
```

---

Также можете зайти в Build Settings и в Strict prototypes установить No:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

уйдут ошибки, которые у Вас на скриншоте.

Comment: Спасибо щас попробую

Comment: Ушли где то 15 штук от Bolts фреймворка, а вот от Parse висят.

Comment: @ShurikTennisist дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать `pod update` проекта который содержит Cocoa pods